# How do I make a subview of a UIScrollView remain stationary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIScrollView` with views in it and I want to make one of them stay in same place. How can I do that?

Right now I have a scroll view that can have anywhere from 1 to 30 or more views on it, and I want one of them to remain at the top of the scroll view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your view controller as the scroll view's delegate, you can implement `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and in that method, you can change the coordinates of your scrollView's subviews to make one of them stationary.

Comment: This is correct when not using the new auto layout feature. With auto layout you need to add constraints connecting the subview of the scroll view with some views outside of the scroll view.

Comment: I am not using auto layout in this project.

Answer (score 0):

@Jsdodgers answer is correct, but I wanted to add the alternative of making the non-scrolling view a sibling of the `UIScrollView` (i.e. they are both subviews of some shared superview).

Comment: actually i wanted the view to scroll left/right along with the scroll view but stay on the top, so it still had to be a subview of the scroll view.